# What is wrong with this shortcode? to include external php file in WordPress posts

Tags: php, shortcode

I want to include a simple html file with a php code inside in my WordPress posts using a Shortcode the code is given below.

```
 function LoadNavigationFile($atts)
{ 
  if ( ! empty( $atts['dirname'] ) ) {
     $dirname = $atts['dirname'];
}

  $str='<php include( "mysite.com/' . $dirname .'" ) ?>';

   return $str;
```

}

```
add_shortcode( 'includeme' , 'LoadNavigationFile' );
```

Nothing is being included and I am getting a blank space,instead of the file.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Look at below function

```
function LoadNavigationFile($atts)
{ 
  if ( ! empty( $atts['dirname_with_file'] ) ) {
     $dirname_with_file = $atts['dirname_with_file'];
  }

  $str=include( get_template_directory() . $dirname_with_file );   

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you are saying

Comment: where do you add shortcode in plugin / theme?

Comment: This shortcode is added in my function.php. I want o write a shortcode that includes external html file in my Wordpress posts.

Comment: <?php include( get_template_directory() . '/dirname/myfile.php'); ?>

Comment: I want this directory:"/dirname/myfile.php"  to be a changeable and not a fix directory to a single file,so that i can use something like [includeme dirname="folder1/new.html"] and for another file [includeme dirname="folder23/new.html"]

Comment: than replace code as per your requirement

Comment: Can you  please write another shortcode to include htmp/php in wordpress posts?

Comment: A code snippet by itself is not an answer. Please explain what is wrong with the OP's code and how your code solves it (not sure it is even what the OP wants)

Comment: Shouldn't the line '<php include( "mysite.com/' . $dirname .'" ) ?>'; work in my wordpress post but it isn't so I need some help.But if you guys think this isn't the right way what might be the possible way,that all I am asking.

Comment: include is right way but like mysite.com/etc/etc.php is wrong way.